# Eigen Vectors are not correct

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have this matrix
$\mathbf{A}=\left[ \begin{array}{rr}
-2& 2 \\
-0.4&0.2
\end{array} \right]$

I need to find its Eigen vectors. The book says its $\left[ \begin{array}{rr}
 2 \\
 0.4597
\end{array} \right]$

$\left[ \begin{array}{rr}
2 \\
1.7403 
\end{array} \right]$
for $\lambda_1=-0.2597$ and $\lambda_2=-1.5403$. I used Matlab and it gave me the same result, but when I do the following, I'm not getting the same result

$(\mathbf{A}-\lambda \mathbf{I})\mathbf{x}$, for instance for $\lambda_2=-1.5403$ what I'm getting is $E_1=4.35E_2$ and $E_1=3.67E_2$. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: the book is wrong.

Comment: what about Matlab

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong. Your calculation will give a multiple of their eigenvector. Eigenvectors are not unique, any multiple is an equivalent eigenvector.

Comment: For $\lambda_2$ does Matlab give $E_1=4.35E_2$ or $3.67E_2$? It can't be both obviously. $4.35$ is correct. Your book is correct but $[2,0.4597]^T$ is the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_2$ and $[2,1.7403]^T$ is the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_1$.

Comment: The first eigenvector you give is associated with the second eigenvalue, and likewise for the second eigenvector and the first eigenvalue. Apart from that, the approximate values are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you're checking it incorrectly.
I don't know what's your $E_1$ and $E_2$, but if $\mathbf{x}_1$ and $\mathbf{x}_2$ are your two eigenvectors, then $(\mathbf{A}-\lambda_1\mathbf{I})\mathbf{x}_1=\mathbf{0}$ and $(\mathbf{A}-\lambda_2\mathbf{I})\mathbf{x}_2=\mathbf{0}$ indeed, so the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are correct.

Edit: the crucial additional information here is given in the comment by Jean-Claude Arbaut: *The first eigenvector you give is associated with the second eigenvalue, and likewise for the second eigenvector and the first eigenvalue.*